# JAVA Paste specific excel range in outlook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have an excel which has certain rows I need to copy in outlook using java code. Actually this data needs to be send in mail. Is it possible in java? How can it be done? I think it can be done in VBA but not sure if it can be done in java. I am using apache poi to create the excel in my code.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a [SMTP Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Outgoing_mail_SMTP_server) that you can use for sending mails (Microsoft Exchange-server can be configured for it, the local Outlook application not! Google Mail and other web-based mail providers usually can be used as well), you can use POI to read the data, take a look at the [quick guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html). Then use the [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/) to send emails, I would take a look at [commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/) as it provides a nice wrapper around Java Mail API.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Selenium webdriver with java for copying and pasting excel data to outlook, also check [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=82) on how to copy and paste data to and from clipboard respectively.

Comment: Provide significant bits of info or code just in case the link breaks in the future